# How to tell if ContentResolver Insert ended successfully?

Tags: android, android-calendar

For the below code I use a genuine id and fake id and the output result doesn't differ at all, besides the fact that a fake id doesn't create a calendar event:

```
int id = getCalendarId(); <-- returns a valid id

String timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault().toString();
String frequency = repeat.trim().toUpperCase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put( CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startInMillis );
values.put( CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "P1800S" );
if( !frequency.equalsIgnoreCase( NO_REPEAT ) ) {
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=" + frequency);
}
values.put( CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone );
values.put( CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, id ); <------------------- this id
values.put( CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title );
values.put( CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description );

if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
    Uri uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert( CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values );
    if( uri != null ) {
        Log.d("xxx", uri.toString());
    }
}
```

Log for genuine id:

> 4736-4736/com.example.test D/xxx:
>   content://com.android.calendar/events/562

Log for fake id:

> 5146-5146/com.example.test D/xxx:
>   content://com.android.calendar/events/563

So how to distinct a good or bad call to `ContentResolver Insert` ?

Comment: The insert itself seems to be fine, as indicated by the fact that you get a `Uri` back. If calendar apps decide not to display your inserted entry, that is a decision of the calendar app, and it will vary by calendar app.

Comment: So there is no clear way to tell if for a valid id the insertion was successful ?

Comment: Again, it looks like the insertion *is* successful. You can check this by querying the `Uri` that you get back and seeing if you get the data that you inserted.